# MySQL Database Error: Packets larger than max_allowed_packet are not allowed - during insert

Tags: mysql

I've never really had this error before but I am doing a rather large insert.  How do I increase this setting?  Also, how do I tell how much I am over what's allowed?  I tried looking up the error, but i'm not using Fogbugz.  Any help would be awesome.

This is a windows installation of mysql.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How to fix this problem : change the value of the [**`max_allowed_packet`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) variable in the configuration of your MySQL server.

How to know how much over what's allowed you are : not sure, but I would say that checking the size *(in bytes)* or your `insert` query should give you an idea.

For more informations, you should take a look at the following section of the MySQL manual : [**C.5.2.10. Packet too large**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html).

Comment: whats the command for it, i try max_allowed_packet=4m or --max_allowed_packet=4m and it says I have an error.

Comment: The best solution is to set this variable in the my.cnf file of your server -- this way, it'll be taken into account each time your server starts.

Comment: well i guess i have a dumb question, where the heck is the my.cnf file or do i create it?  i've searched my entire server and cant find it

Comment: I don't really know where this file is on windows, sorry *(I usually work with Linux servers)* ; judging from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-create-option-file.html you might have to create it ?

Answer (score 15):

To set the max to 16MB for example, without requiring a restart, run:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 16777216
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue while using XAMPP and what I did was to open the my.ini file via the Config button of MySQL on the XAMPP control and changing max_allowed_packet from 1M to 100M. It solved my problem.